# How to filter subdocument in mongoose along with population

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

My document Users contains following data:

```
{  "name" : "Plantation",
    "image" : "1535695444692.jpg",
    "type" : "csr",
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5b7d598e86acd5b4171a2587"),
    "joining" : [ 
        {
            "csr" : ObjectId("5b8a923f3284ca8451980a43"),
            "volunteer" : ObjectId("5b891c4805540dfc0d541f72"),
            "joined" : false
        }, 
        {
            "csr" : ObjectId("5b8a923f3284ca8451980a43"),
            "volunteer" : ObjectId("5b891c4805540dfc0d541f73"),
            "joined" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to apply a filter on `joining` subdocument where csr `id` is *"5b8a923f3284ca8451980a43"* if this conditions got matched then `joining` subdocument should contain all matching data,otherwise `joining` subdocument can be empty. I also want to populate `joining.volunteer` data.

I have used the following code but it only returned first matched subdocument.

```
Users.findOne({ _id: req.params.id },{'joining':{$elemMatch:{csr:'5b7d598e86acd5b4171a2587'}}}).populate('joining.volunteer').then(function (opportunity) {
        return res.json({ opportunity: opportunity });
    }).catch(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Users.find({_id: req.params.id},{'joining':{$elemMatch:{csr: CSR_ID }}}).populate({path: 'joining',populate:{
                path: 'volunteer',
                model: 'YOUR volunteer MODEL NAME'
}})
```